# Badge Suggestion: "Comment Master" "Comment Guru"

Tags: feature-request, badge-request

I just checked the badge list for people who leave comments on other people's questions and answers and found only two out of which one is difficult to be obtained.

One is `PUNDIT - Left 10 comments with score of 5 or more`

Other is `COMMENTATOR - Left 10 comments` which is very easy to obtain.

I am thinking if there can be badge following combination of these. One for Silver named "Comment Master" and One for Gold named "Comment Guru".

The conditions for these badges would be as follows -

- "**Comment Master**" - Left comments with total score for all comments together reaches 200
- "**Comment Guru**" - Left comments with total score for all comments together reaches 1000

This would atleast keep people interested in posting comments wherever required instead of adding unnecessary answers for the greed of reputation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [More badges for comments / Bronze and gold versions of "Pundit"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45580/more-badges-for-comments-bronze-and-gold-versions-of-pundit)

Comment: ["We very intentionally do not have a gold comment badge, and never will." -Jeff](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45580/more-badges-for-comments-bronze-and-gold-versions-of-pundit/78049#78049)

Comment: @Popular Demand - Was just wondering if there is any reason behind this?. Is this because comments are not as encouraged as the votes in the system?

Comment: you'll have to ask Jeff if you want the official answer. But I believe you're right.

Comment: @Popular Demand - haha... true. Thanks. Have asked jeff for reason in his answer thread itself..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is a great idea, but not for counting the *overall* score for all comments together. I would propose some higher-ranking badges instead:

```
- Left 5 comments with score 25 or more

- Left 5 comments with score 100 or more
```

Comment: I would prefer raising the number of high-ranking comments, while reducing the threshold for what is a "high-ranking" comment. I don't think we need to encourage 100+ votes on individual comments, do we?  10 or 20 comments of score 10 sounds more realistic.

Comment: Relevant SEDE queries: [25](http://odata.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/293/pundit-badge-standings?Score=25) and [100](http://odata.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/293/pundit-badge-standings?Score=100). Much as I might like the 100 version, I'd have to say it's pretty pointless.

Comment: Seriously, Ether is right. Almost all 100+ vote comments are jokes anyway.

Comment: Anything for total votes counted together for all comments left by a user? I feel, 25 and 100 on individual comment is too much. Is there a way to find out how many users have got this anyway? very few I guess.