# Analyst badge: 10 comments with score of 10 or more

Tags: feature-request, comments, badge-request, comment-voting, comment-badges

I see that Area 51 has an **[Analyst badge](http://area51.stackexchange.com/badges/94/analyst)** — *Left 10 comments with score of 10 or more*. It also has the **Commentator** (10 comments) and **Pundit** (10 comments/5 score) badges, which the SE sites all have.

So will/can StackOverflow and the SE sites get an Analyst badge too?

Comment: [The existence of this badge confuses me](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45580/more-badges-for-comments-bronze-and-gold-versions-of-pundit/78049#78049).

Comment: @Tim - that is something I was not aware of or had seen and forgotten (I did search, but by the title of the badge).  Now, I am confused, too...

Comment: I'm guessing it's because comments serve a slightly different function on Area 51 than they do on regular sites on the SE network.